# Travelling outside of UK on a tourist visa

Tags: visas

I am a Canadian citizen and currently visiting the UK to be with my girlfriend. I have the 6 month tourist visa stamp and have a return flight booked back to Canada on February 2nd.

My question is can I travel to Barcelona with my girlfriend for a few days before I fly back to Canada. Will they allow me back into the UK to get on my flight back to Canada?

Comment: Um, yes? Why wouldn't they?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Out of concern that the OP is attempting a “visa run” and would want to stay another six months? (Not saying it's an issue but I am guessing that's the concern here).

Comment: that is most definitely not the situation and I have only been in the UK for 3 months.

Comment: @Xavier it does not matter whether your trip to Barcelona is a visa run.  What matters is whether the UK border officer *suspects* that the trip is a visa run.

Answer (score 1):

No it shouldn't be a problem for you to go back to the UK, the worst is you might be asked about it but you have a perfectly valid reason to do so and you could show your flight booking as evidence.